# Access devices on local network when running Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I have some smart wifi devices on my network I can see from a script on my Mac. But running the same script from within a Docker container those devices are not visible.

I assume this is related to Docker for Mac's inability to connect to the host's network using `--network host` or `network_mode: host`. I also assume this issue wouldn't exist on a Linux machine but I don't have one to test on.

What is the workaround?

Edit:

Confirmed this worked fine when running inside an Ubuntu virtualbox, but I'd really not have to develop inside it.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the container with network option as host, the container will share the network stack of the host. Thus any device reachable from you host should be reachable by the container.

```
docker run --network host ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot. When using `docker-compose` and setting `network_mode: host` for the service, it would not work. Is that expected?

Comment: After further research I'm fairly confident this is not a solution due to the way Docker for Mac works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding containers to a network would allow them to communicate with each other but if you want to access other services running on host then **host.docker.internal** (from 18.03+). I had to do the same in a mac mini setup to access external service. 
[https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/]

If you have to access a service on another host then you can setup an nginx server on the docker host and a proxy pass rule to direct it to the remote service.